# Convert WebElement to int

Tags: java, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver

What is the proper way to convert a WebElement to an int? Is this even possible?

Comment: You mean the text of an element??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a java problem, not a Selenium problem. You can use:

```
driver.findElement(By...locator).getText().toInteger()    // this works in Groovy only
```

or you can use

```
Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By...locator).getText());    // this works in Java or Groovy
```

Comment: The second option works perfect for me, appreciate it.

Comment: The first option won't compile -- toInteger() is not a method that can be called off of a String.

Comment: @TJamesBoone is right, for Java. I code most of my tests in Groovy, where this works all day long.

Comment: @TJamesBoone Thanx to SoapUI, I don't think I know how to write pure-Java anymore. ;)